# Access VBA recordset string comparison not working with wildcard

Tags: string, ms-access, vba, recordset

I have loads of experience using VBA in Excel but very little experience using VBA in Access 2010. I'm trying to delete records from a recordset where one of the fields ends in "_X". When I use a wildcard the comparison fails. When I use a specific string, the comparison works as expected. Here is the Code that I am using.

```
Dim db As Database: Set db = CurrentDb
Dim tbl As Recordset: Set tbl = db.OpenRecordset("WRITEON")
With tbl
    Do Until .EOF
        If ![ACOD] = "*_X" Then '"$ICP_X" works
            Debug.Print ![ACOD] 'For testing
            '.Delete
        End If
    .MoveNext
    Loop
End With
tbl.Close
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Like` instead of `=` when you're comparing a text value to a pattern.

```vb
If ![ACOD] Like "*_X" Then
    Debug.Print ![ACOD]
End If
```

That should do what you want, but I'm not so sure evaluating each record in a recordset to delete the matches is the best way.  You could accomplish the same result by executing a `DELETE` query which uses that same pattern to identify which rows should be deleted.

```sql
DELETE FROM WRITEON
WHERE [ACOD] Like "*_X";
```

Comment: Using "Like" worked like a charm. I posted this question out of frustration mostly. I had already gone the "DELETE" query route. Here's what I used instead:  `Dim SQL As String
SQL = "DELETE * FROM WRITEON WHERE WRITEON.ACOD Like '*_X'"
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
DoCmd.SetWarnings True`

Comment: OK, I understand now.  Thanks.  Consider using `CurrentDb.Execute SQL, dbFailOnError` instead of `DoCmd.RunSQL`.  With that method, you don't need to turn `SetWarnings` off.  With `SetWarnings` off, you suppress information which could be helpful for troubleshooting.

Comment: Excellent advice! Thank you. I am definitely uncomfortable using the `SetWarnings off/on` workaround. Your way is much better.