# Wildcard in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, wildcard, ms-access-2013

This is kind of a follow up question to this post: [Access VBA recordset string comparison not working with wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28842454/access-vba-recordset-string-comparison-not-working-with-wildcard) but I don't have the rep to answer/comment on it to ask it in house. What I'm curious about is this line of code specifically:

```
If ![ACOD] = "*_X" Then '"$ICP_X" works
        Debug.Print ![ACOD] 'For testing
        '.Delete
End If
```

I want to know if this can be modified so that on a button click, it looks at all fields in a form with the field name of `*_New` (with the hope to catch all fields where the name ends in `_New`) and if they are not `Null` then confirm that the user wanted to make a the change indicated in the field. I was thinking of something along the lines like this:

```
If Not isNull(*_New.value) Then
   If Msgbox ("Do you want to make these changes?",vbOKCancel, "Confirm Changes") = 1 Then
      '### Do something with the record ###
   End If
End If
```

**EDIT**

As of posting the above information, I did not have the Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions Reference installed, currently I have version 5.5 (it was the latest version). With that installed (referenced?) and seeing the information from this site [MS Access with VBA Regex](http://msaccessinfo.blogspot.com/2013/04/regular-expressions-in-access-vba.html), I'm wondering if it's better to do something like this:

```
Dim re As RegExp
Set re = New RegExp
re.IgnoreCase = True
re.Global = True
re.Pattern = "*_New"
If ##Not sure on syntax to match all fields## Then
   Msgbox(##Same stuff as above MsgBox##)
End If
```

**EDIT 2**

Here's a sample case for my form I'm working on. Each of the fields to the right have names that end in `_New`. What I want to do is on the button click, to check and see what fields on the right have been filled in and ask the user if they want to confirm the changes to the record.

[image: Sample case for testing form]

Comment: You did the right thing asking this as a new question - on StackOverflow, it is intended that all questions be separate and searchable on their own and not buried in another. Linking to that related question is a great way to start it off!

Comment: All fields means? just text boxes or any kind of control?

Comment: BTW: The previous question is related to SQL and its completely different from searching controls in a form/object.

Comment: The previous question was answered and taken care of in SQL, yes, but was originally asked (as far as I can tell) for VBA.

Comment: How would that look though? I don't want to check each individual field in their own if statement.

Comment: Yes, I was planning on doing it with an OnClick command

Comment: Logically what should happen is the user uses the dropdown list at the top to select a claim they want to edit, they then edit the fields they want to change on the right side and click the button to save them and update the record in the database. If there are no changes to a field then that field in the table it's linked to should remain unchanged, otherwise update it with the information in the right side fields.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve but there is a way to access the control collection in a form. Here is a public function where you can loop through all controls and check its name.

```
Public Function FN_CONFIRM_CHANGES(iSender As Form)
    Dim mCtl As control
    For Each mCtl In iSender
        If VBA.Right(mCtl.name, 4) = "_New" Then
            Debug.Print mCtl.name & " is a match and its a " & VBA.TypeName(mCtl)
        End If
    Next mCtl
End Function
```

Call this function like

```
FN_CONFIRM_CHANGES Me 'Where me is referencing the form you are in.
```

You can modify the above code to return a boolean value to stop further execution if user decided not to save your changes or whatever logic you are trying to implement.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is search the form for fields where the name ends in `_New` and check if there is anything other than the default `Null` value in those fields matching the `_New` criteria. Since I have more rep now (when I posted the question I only had 10 Rep), I'll edit my OP and attach a screenshot of my form. Hopefully it'll clarify things a bit

Comment: if your form is a bounded form all your changes will be automatically saved. I don't think it is a good idea to prompt message for each control. In  case if you have >10 controls, i personally wouldn't want to click 10 times to save a record. @TravisPatterson

Comment: granted, I wouldn't either. I mean eventually it's going to be a message box or something that shows the fields that are about to be edited as a list (rather than an individual message box for each control) with a cancel button (`vbOKCancel`) to allow them to go back and change it.

Comment: from my experience working with clients, i can tell you something.. your end-user never going to bother reading whats on the messagebox. they will click yes for anything and no if they are don't want to. Just perform a single question. Would you like to save changed yes/no thats it... @TravisPatterson